# How to use jquery scroll to element when there's a fixed position header?

Tags: jquery

I've a div header with position: fixed so it will always stay on the top. Then below I've another div and I want to scroll to that element after submit (when errors occurred). I tried all those jquery scrollTop, offset().top, etc. but nothing works. I wonder if it's cuz there's like in a frame now so I won't able to?

Anyone know how?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found this and it works but it will scroll to the top instead of specific element though.

window.scrollTo(0, 0);